# Template specialization with classes

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to implement Template specialization. I delcared template and class:

```
template <class T>
class Person{

public:

        Person(char one, T two){

            this -> prv  = one;
            this -> druh = two;

        }
        void explain();

private:

    char prv;
    T druh;

};
```

and declared its getter

```
template <class T>

void Person<T>::explain(){

    cout << "Druh isnt char" << endl;

}
```

Now if i create object with data type other than char , it will indeeed output the "Druh isnt char" e.g

```
 Person <int> obj('a',5);    
 obj1.explain();  // "Druh isnt char"
```

I want to use specialization , so when the 2nd argument is char it will say `"Druh is char"`

I tried it using :

/********* Template specialization ***********/

```
template<>

class Person<char>{

public:
        Person(char one, char two){

           this-> prv = one;
           this-> druh = two;

        }
        void explain();

};
```

and defined explain method again

```
void Person<char>::explain(){

    cout << "Druh is a char " << endl;

}
```

But i am getting this error

> 'class Person' has no member named 'prv'|

Why is this happening? Should it take the private variables from first declaration of class Person? Doesnt `templat<>` says to compiler that i am not creating another Object just using template specification?

Comment: class `Person<char>` does not contain a member called `prv`.

Comment: `Should it take the private variables from first declaration of class Person?` No. Why do you think it should do so?

Comment: What is the point of using template specialization then? Why not just define another class.

Comment: Template specialization isn't inheritance

Comment: @user3706129: When you specialize a class template, you are creating another class.  The reason you specialize is to make it so the caller can still be generic.  For example, the caller may be using `Person<T>`.  The specialization allows them to not have to check whether `T` is a `char` to know which class to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specialize only the method:

```
template <>
void Person<char>::explain(){
    cout << "Druh is char" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A simpler way of achieving what you want to do is this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    A() : c('z') {
    }
    void printChar() {
        std::cout << "Not a char!" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    char c;
};

template <>
void A<char>::printChar() {
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Since what you want is to specialize the member function, and not the entire class.